# SVG step chart with rounded corners

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, charts

How can I create step chart with smooth rounded corners like on example below?

[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8u9c.png)

Corners radius depends on coords-differences between steps.

I used d3.js links and tried to create custom SVG-curves, but can't implement it right way.

I'd appreciate any ideas. Maybe there is some lib for that?

UPD: polyline code for @exaneta

```
<polyline points="10,40 15,45 30,70 35,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></polyline>
```

Comment: If I have a polyline connecting points on an svg canvas, I can, using javascript, calculate the coordinates for a quadratic Bézier curve for the rounded corners. If this is what you need please edit your question and add some svg code with the polyline.

Comment: @enxaneta, to be honest, I don't really understand how this is going to work. I tried to describe the necessary piece of graphics (connecting line) with a polyline. You can see it in the question.

How can I round the corners for such a polyline?

Comment: For each line segment, you are going to have to calculate the X,Y coords of the point N units before the end of the line. Then N units along from the start of the next line. Then connect thoose two points with a bezier curve (ie a `Q` path command) or an arc (`A` path command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented you can use javascript to calculate the coordinates for a quadratic Bézier curve for the rounded corners. The control point of the Bézier is the point of the polyline. Then you need to get the starting and the ending points for the Bézier as a point  at the distance `r` from the control point on the polyline.
Once you have all the points for the new path you can use them to build the value for the `d` attribute of `thePath`.

Please make sure the `r` variable has reasonable size.

```js
let polypoints = poly.getAttribute("points");
let r = 5; // distance for the curvature

function getPoints(poly) {
  // poly is the polygon's element d attribute
  let polyPoints = poly
    .replace(/(\r?\n|\r|\t)+/g, "")
    .replace(/\-/g, " -")
    .split(/[\s,]+/);
  polyPoints = removeEmptyElements(polyPoints);
  let points = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < polyPoints.length; i += 2) {
    let temp = [Number(polyPoints[i]), Number(polyPoints[i + 1])];
    points.push(temp);
  }
  return points;////[[10, 40],[15, 45],[30, 70],[35, 75]]
}

function getAngle(c, l) {
  let delta_x = l.x - c.x;
  let delta_y = l.y - c.y;
  let a = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
  return a; //in radians;
}

function removeEmptyElements(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == "") {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return array;
}

function polygonWithRoundedCorners(poly, r) {
  let points = getPoints(poly);
  //move to the first point
  let d = `M${points[0][0]},${points[0][1]}`;
  
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let previous = i - 1;
    let next = i + 1;
    let c = {};//the control point
    c.x = points[i][0];
    c.y = points[i][1];
    let l1 = {};
    l1.x = points[previous][0];
    l1.y = points[previous][1];
    let l2 = {};
    l2.x = points[next][0];
    l2.y = points[next][1];
    let a1 = getAngle(c, l1);
    let a2 = getAngle(c, l2);

    //if great precision is needed remove .toFixed(3)
    //x1 and y1 are defining the start point of the Bézier
    let x1 = (c.x + r * Math.cos(a1)).toFixed(3);
    let y1 = (c.y + r * Math.sin(a1)).toFixed(3);
    //x2 and y2 are defining the end point of the Bézier
    let x2 = (c.x + r * Math.cos(a2)).toFixed(3);
    let y2 = (c.y + r * Math.sin(a2)).toFixed(3);
    //build the d attribute
    d += "L" + x1 + "," + y1 + " Q" + c.x + "," + c.y + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
  }
  //move to the last point and return the d attribute
  return (d += `L${points[points.length - 1][0]},${
    points[points.length - 1][1]
  }`);
}

thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", polygonWithRoundedCorners(polypoints, r));
```

```css
svg{border:solid;width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 30 55 55">
<polyline id="poly" points="10,40 15,45 30,70 35,75" fill="none" stroke="black" ></polyline>  
<path id="thePath" fill="none" stroke="red"  /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!